# Cannot insert json string to sqlite in App

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, sqlite

I'm trying to insert a json string to sqlite in my app. But it doesn't complete the insert query. I think there might be a problem with the format of the json string maybe? Because when I insert a regular string it works. Please let me know if you can see where I wen't wrong. Here is the code:

```
    NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(self.chosenPhoto, 0.5f);
    NSString *base64StringOfImage = [imageData base64EncodedStringWithOptions:0];
    MCYProduct *newProduct = [[MCYProduct alloc] initWithProductName:self.textFieldName.text ProductDescription:self.textViewDescription.text ProductPrice:@([self.textFieldPrice.text integerValue]) ProductSalePrice:@([self.textFieldSalePrice.text integerValue]) ProductColors:self.chosenColors ProductStores:dictionaryStores ProductPhoto:self.chosenPhoto];
    NSDictionary *dictionaryProduct = @{@"name": newProduct.name, @"description:": newProduct.description, @"price": newProduct.price, @"salePrice:": newProduct.salePrice, @"colors": newProduct.colors, @"stores:": newProduct.stores, @"photo": base64StringOfImage};

    NSError *writeError = nil;
    NSData *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:dictionaryProduct options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted error:&writeError];
    NSString *jsonString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:jsonData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSLog(@"JSON Output: %@", jsonString);

    sqlite3 *sqlite;
    NSString *directoryDocuments;
    NSArray *directoryPath;
    NSString *databasePath;
    directoryPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    directoryDocuments = [directoryPath objectAtIndex:0];
    databasePath = [[NSString alloc] initWithString: [directoryDocuments stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"products.db"]];
    const char *dbPath = [databasePath UTF8String];
    sqlite3_stmt *statement;

    if (sqlite3_open(dbPath, &sqlite) == SQLITE_OK)
    {
        NSMutableString *mutableJsonString = [[NSMutableString alloc]initWithData:jsonData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        [mutableJsonString replaceOccurrencesOfString:@"\""  withString:@"\\\"" options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch range:NSMakeRange(0, [mutableJsonString length])];

        jsonString = mutableJsonString;

        NSString *insertSQL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"INSERT INTO PRODUCTS (JSON) VALUES ('%@')",jsonString];
        const char *insert_stmt = [insertSQL UTF8String];
        sqlite3_prepare_v2(sqlite, insert_stmt, -1, &statement, NULL);
        if (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_DONE)
        {
            NSLog(@"Product added");
        } else {
            NSLog(@"Failed to add Product");
        }
        sqlite3_finalize(statement);
        sqlite3_close(sqlite);
    }
```

Comment: Never use `stringWithFormat` to bind values into a query. Do it properly using the `sqlite3_bind_xxx` functions.

Comment: it worked like this:

    sqlite3_stmt *statement;
        
        if (sqlite3_open(dbPath, &sqlite) == SQLITE_OK)
        {
            NSString *insertSQL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"INSERT INTO PRODUCTS (JSON) VALUES (?)"];
            const char *insert_stmt = [insertSQL UTF8String];
            sqlite3_prepare_v2(sqlite, insert_stmt, -1, &statement, NULL);
            sqlite3_bind_text(statement, 1, [jsonString UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);

Thanks rmaddy!

Comment: Note that there's no point in the stringWithFormat in your comment above -- it's just wasted motion.  Assign the string literal directly to `insertSQL`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is to use bind like this:

```
sqlite3_stmt *statement;
if (sqlite3_open(dbPath, &sqlite) == SQLITE_OK) { 
    NSString *insertSQL = @"INSERT INTO PRODUCTS (JSON) VALUES (?)"; 
    const char *insert_stmt = [insertSQL UTF8String]; 
    sqlite3_prepare_v2(sqlite, insert_stmt, -1, &statement, NULL); 
    sqlite3_bind_text(statement, 1, [jsonString UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
}
```